# Clearing Values in Iframe on Web Site

Tags: iframe

I am working with a Iframe code for a web page. When I embed it on the page, I find that when I come back the form values are what I had previously inputed. I want to have the values of the form to be cleared.

Here is my code:  `<iframe src="https://go.sabertorch.com/l/902951/2021-01-20/4wl1" width="100%" height="500" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>`

Is there anything that I can add to make sure that values are cleared.

Comment: Hi Tim, It appears you have forgotten to paste your code .

Comment: Thanks, @Joshua! :-)